# Multiple Projects in an MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, multi-project

I am working on an MVC3 application at the moment.  I also have a requirement to create custom membership providers for this appl.  What I was hoping to do was create a separate MVC3 solution/project with the classes + controllers/views for the membership stuff, so that I can potentially reuse it in other applications as required.

- Is this the best way to do this? Or is there any other recommended way?
- If I go this route, create the project and then add it to the initial app (as an existing item), how would I get to the controllers/views on the user project?  is it just a case of setting up the routes correctly?   Can Areas be used for this?

Thank you for your insights.

Comment: I think this is depend on your requirement and your development environment. its better to have separate layers plus different projects for different task, like Database stuff, validation stuff etc. but if you need to finish project with tiny time line do it in one. hope this might help you to get some start or do more investigation. any way if you have more clarification do not hesitate to comment over here